# Vertical side text in margin

Tags: minipage

I'm using article document class. I want on one page to create a left margin with a vertical text starting from the bottom.

[image: result]

I tried using minipages and the rotating package but I was not able to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome! Here is one possible way using `tikzpagenodes`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just for dummy text
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \draw ([xshift=-1em]current page text area.west|-current page.south) 
 --
  ([xshift=-1em]current page text area.west|-current page.north)
  node[pos=0.1,sloped,anchor=south west,font=\sffamily] {Some side text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `eso-pic`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic, rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}%

\begin{document}   

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\AtTextLowerLeft{\llap{\rotatebox[origin=lb]{90}{\large\sffamily Some side text}\quad\rule{0.8pt}{\textheight}\enspace}}}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to add a line between the margin and the text  ?

Comment: Do you mean a vertical line? Which length?

Comment: The height of the page minus the margins like the other answer

Comment: Yes, it is very simple with basic tools. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. I already use the other answer in my code but it's interesting to understand how these packages work.

Comment: `eso-pic` is a package dedicated to this kid of things ((`\AddToShipoutPicture`, without a star, would add the stuff on each page).. You should take a look at the documentation, which is short and pretty clear.

Comment: @louisld I confirm that `eco-pic`, and `atbegshi` which it is based on, is a great package, which I use a lot when I want to put stuff on the background or foreground of several pages. I like to combine them with `tikzpagenodes` which makes it absolutely straightforward to access all coordinates of the page and makes it possible to go beyond vertical or horizontal lines without the need of manual adjustments.